# Trying to GET a sign up form and login form in React.js Node.js and PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js

Hello guys I have been working on a project here but I am stuck for now. I have been trying t connect the signup form to the server but whenever I try to submit the form, it is not being submitted thus nothing is adding to the database. I am using PostgreSQL as my local server. So I don't know if its my connection. I feel very confused about it for now and your assist will help me

Server.js code

```
    //use dotenv for development
require("dotenv").config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8082;
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const helmet = require("helmet");
const compression = require("compression");
const knexConfig = require("./db/knexfile");
const knex = require("knex")(knexConfig[ENV]);
const morgan = require("morgan");
const knexLogger = require("knex-logger");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

// this must be before other app.use statements
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Seperated Routes for each Resource
const usersRoute = require("./routes/users");
const messagesRoute = require("./routes/messages");
const reviewsRoute = require("./routes/reviews");

app.use(compression());
app.use(helmet());
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const origin = {
  origin: isProduction ? "http://localhost:3000" : "*"
};
app.use(cors(origin));

const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 1 * 60 * 1000, // 1 minute
  max: 30 // 30 requests
});

app.use(limiter);

// Load the logger first so all (static) HTTP requests are logged to STDOUT
// 'dev' = Concise output colored by response status for development use.
//         The :status token will be colored red for server error codes, yellow for client error codes, cyan for redirection codes, and uncolored for all other codes.
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// Log knex SQL queries to STDOUT as well
app.use(knexLogger(knex));

// Mount all resource routes
app.use("/api/users", usersRoute(knex));
app.use("/api/messages", messagesRoute(knex));
app.use("/api/reviews", reviewsRoute(knex));

// Home page
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    user: "Lighthouse Labs"
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Example app listening on port " + PORT);
});
```

Users.js

```
    exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('users', function (table) {
      table.increments('id');
      table.integer('role');
      table.string('first_name');
      table.string('last_name');
      table.string('email');
      table.string('phone_number');
      table.string('avatar');
      table.string('postal_code');
      table.string('street_address');
      table.string('city');
    });
  };
  
  exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('users');
  };
```

Sign up.js

```
  import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Form, Col, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./styles/signup.css";

export default function Signup() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="returning-user">
        <p className="return-label">Returning User?</p>
        <Link to="/login" className="login-link">
          Login
        </Link>
      </div>

      <Form className="signup-form">
        <h3>New User Signup</h3>
        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridFirstName">
            <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="First name" />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridLastName">
            <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Form.Row className="password-signup">
          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPasswordConfirm">
            <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password Confirmation" />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Form.Group controlId="formGridPhone">
          <Form.Label>Phone Number</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control placeholder="070-000-0000" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="formGridAddress">
          <Form.Label>Street Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control placeholder="1234 Main Street" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
            <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control placeholder="Nairobi" />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridProvince">
            <Form.Label>Province</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control placeholder="e.g Runda" />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPostal">
            <Form.Label>Postal Code</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Button variant="info" type="submit" className="signupBtn" block>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

knex.js

```
   //use dotenv for development
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'postgres',
      password: '',
      database: 'dogwalk',
      port: '5432'
      
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: "./db/migrations",
      tableName: "migrations"
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: "./db/seeds"
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: "pg",
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL + "?ssl=true",
    pool: {
      min: 0,
      max: 15
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: "./db/migrations",
      tableName: "migrations"
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: "./db/seeds"
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: in the code you provided, it's not possible to know where the data will post the form, since there's no route info where the data will posted (no `form method="post" action="/users/someroute"` )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have added the extra codes. Please assist